# How can I know the type of filter from its cutoff frequency?

Tags: filters, frequency-response

So I have the following equation 
$$
y[n]=0.9y[n-1]+0.1x[n]
$$

We can find easily find the transfer function, which is

$$
H(z)=\frac{0.1}{1-0.9z^{-1}}
$$

and from that, the frequency response, which is

$$
H(e^{j \omega})=\frac{0.1}{1-0.9 e^{-j \omega}}
$$

To find the cutoff frequency we just make the magnitude of the above equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then, $\omega_0 = 0.0675\Rightarrow f_0 = 0.0107$.

Okay, so how can we say that given  $f_0 = f_c$ the filter is a LPF or HPF?

Comment: Does the frequency response increase or decrease as the frequency increases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types of filters, such as LPF, HPF, BPF or BSF, are not described by their cutoff frequencies $f_c$ but through their **passband** or **stopband** frequency $\omega$ region.

For example, in your case of the filter $H(z) = 1 / (1 - 0.9 z^{-1})$, the passband is in the low frequencies (where the magnitude of the frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ is greater than $1/\sqrt{2}$. And by your definition that region corresponds to $\omega \in (-f_c , f_c)$ which indicates a **lowpass** range of frequencies.

Other filters like HPF and BPF follow in a similar manner. Note that specific filters such as **comb** or **notch** types are defined in a different style than this.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the Z Transform

\begin{equation}
H(z) = \frac{0.1}{1-0.9z^{-1}}
\end{equation}

Now get the frequency response by evaluating 
\begin{equation}
 H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{0.1}{1-0.9z^{-1}} \Bigr|_{z = e^{j\omega}}  
\end{equation}

You can now plot magnitude and phase for a given frequency $\omega$

Comment: you're correct mitch.  i have enough rep that i can edit his question.  the only thing i need to do to fix yours (which is **not** the same as completing it) is to change $w$ to $\omega$.